# Python imaplib .search email subject Chinese got error

Tags: python, email, imap, imaplib, chinese-locale

I want to use imaplib to search particular emails, which subjects contain Chinese.
I got the error like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

so i use .encode to encode to 'UTF-8', and I got nothing. The print print out is

```
0
[]
```

The right answer should be 71, which I search on my inbox through my mail.
This is my code:

```
import imaplib,email
host = 'imap.263.net'
user = '***@***'
psw = '*****'
count = 0
con = imaplib.IMAP4(host,143)
con.login(user,psw)
con.select('INBOX',readonly =True)
eva = '日报'
# eva = eva.encode('utf-8') 
resp,liujf = con.search('UTF-8','SUBJECT','%s'%eva, 'Since','01-Feb-2018')
items = liujf[0].split()
print(len(items))
print(items)
```

I guess it should be unicode problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in a raw Unicode string where you should be passing in the string as a sequence of UTF-8 bytes. You've even labelled it as UTF-8! This suggests you might want to read up on the difference.

Change

```
'%s'%eva
```

to

```
eva.encode('utf-8')
```

For more background, maybe read https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#UTF8 and/or https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

The construct `'%s'%string` is just an ugly and unidiomatic way to say `string` but here it's actually an error: `'%s'%string.encode('utf-8')` produces a byte string but then interpolates it into a Unicode string which produces completely the wrong result.  Observe:

```
>>> eva = '日报'
>>> eva.encode('utf-8')              # correct
b'\xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x8a\xa5'
>>> '%s'%eva.encode('utf-8')         # incorrect
"b'\\xe6\\x97\\xa5\\xe6\\x8a\\xa5'"
>>> b'%s'%eva.encode('utf-8')        # correct but terribly fugly
b'\xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x8a\xa5'
```

Notice how `'%s'%eva.encode('utf-8')` takes the encoded byte string and converts it *back* into a Unicode representation.  The commented-out line shows that you tried `eva = eva.encode('utf-8')` but then apparently ended up with the wrong result because of the unnecessary `%` interpolation into a Unicode string.

Comment: I change '%s'%eva into eva.encode('utf-8'). The code now is: resp,liujf = con.search('utf-8','SUBJECT',eva.encode('utf-8'), 'Since','01-Feb-2018'). The result is right. Thanks!!!

Comment: Still `'%s'%something` is a wasteful and inelegant way to write `something`.

Comment: What is different between: eva = eva.encode('utf-8')
resp,liujf = con.search('utf-8','SUBJECT','%s'%eva,  and  eva.encode('utf-8')

Comment: Oh yeah, then `'%s'%eva` is actually wrong because you are converting it back to Unicode (if I understand your question correctly).  `b'%s'%eva` would do the right thing and merely be horrendously ugly.  See updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should first decode and then encode the Chinese literals.If we interpret it as latin-1 encoded, then you decode it first and then encode it.
Ex- eva.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')

Comment: it shows an error: eva = eva.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: There is no way to decode Unicode into Latin-1 if the Unicode string contains characters which cannot be represented in Latin-1. If you have a byte string then "decoding" it as Latin-1 will convert it into a Unicode string but then you have a bug somewhere else -- Python 3 quite on purpose forces you to know the encoding of your data, or else keep it as bytes.